# como usar o case com um select vindo do html

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, case

Bom dia pessoal,

preciso puxar dados do banco de dados,
mas queria que o usuário pudesse escolher a partir de que dados qual valor pesquisar.

Meu código `html`:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="frmBusca" action="Exibindo.php">

Pesquisar pedido:<input type="text" name="busca" id="busca">
<input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">
 <select name="opcao">
        <option>Numero bl</option>
        <option>Conteiner</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
```

Agora lá no `php`:

```
<?php 
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$banco = mysql_select_db("cliente_svn") or die(mysql_error());
$busca = $_POST['busca'];
$opcao = $_POST['opcao'];

case ($opcao = "Numero bl"):
```

Queria saber a formatação correta pra chamar o `case`.

Obrigada!

Comment: poderia postar o codigo `HTML` e a parte onde você a requisicao com o `PHP` na base de dados ?

Comment: eu estou tentando posta o HTML mas ele tá compilando o código!

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="frmBusca" action="Exibindo.php">

Pesquisar pedido:<input type="text" name="busca" id="busca">
<input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">
 <select name="opcao">
     <option>Numero bl</option>
     <option>Conteiner</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: um pedaço do php

Comment: $query_select = "SELECT * FROM novo_pedido WHERE num_bl = '$busca'";
 $select = mysql_query($query_select,$conexao);
 

 if ($select) {
  
  echo "<form class='col_md_16'>";
  echo "<label>Listagem de conteiners</label>
    <table class='table-erika'><tr><td>Conteiner</td>
    <td>Tamanho</td>
    <td>Peso</td>
    </tr>";
    
  while ($escrever = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
   echo "<tr><td>".$escrever['conteiner']."</td><td>".$escrever['tamanho_cont']."</td><td>".$escrever['peso_cont']."</td></tr>";

Comment: Qual é o problema  no teu codigo ? O que nao funciona ?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas você deve fazer alguns ajustes no seu código, por exemplo, o `input` de Busca tem o `name` buscar, mas no `php` você tenta pegar com o `POST` de busca. E seus `options` no `select` estão sem `value`.

Comment: eu editei minha pergunta lá, vê se agora dá pra entender.

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi a pergunta, você pode fazer assim :

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" name="frmBusca" action="Exibindo.php">
    <label for="busca">Pesquisar pedido:</label>
    <input type="text" name="busca" id="busca">
    <select name="opcao">
        <option value="1">Numero bl</option>
        <option value="2">Conteiner</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$banco = mysql_select_db("cliente_svn") or die(mysql_error());
$busca = isset($_POST['busca']) ? $_POST['busca'] : '';
$opcao = isset($_POST['opcao']) ? $_POST['opcao'] : '';

switch($opcao){
    case '2':
        $column = "conteiner";
        break;
    default: // se for qualquer outro valor imprevisto, inclusive o 1
        $column = "num_bl";
}   

$query_select = "SELECT * FROM novo_pedido WHERE $column = '$busca'";
```

Seria bom também usar `mysqli`.

[Por que não devemos usar funções 'mysql_*' ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Creio que entendi o que você deseja, para ser mais dinâmico usaria o jQuery,é bem simples.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label>Pesquisar pedido:<input type="text" name="busca" id="busca"></label>
<input type="button" value="Buscar" id="buscar">
<select name="opcao">
   <option value="Numero_bl">Numero bl</option>
   <option value="Conteiner">Conteiner</option>
</select>
<div id="resultado"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#buscar").click(function(){
     $("#resultado").load("arquivo.php");
   });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Coloque no value das `<options>` o nome das colunas exatamente que deseja pesquisar conforme seleção.

**arquivo.php**

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "cliente_svn";
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("A Conexão Falhou: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }


$busca = $_POST['busca']; //blablabla
$opcao = $_POST['opcao']; //Numero_bl
//digamos que o numero bl seja a coluna;

$select = "SELECT * from tabela where $opcao = '$busca'";
$result = $conn->query($select);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   echo "<p>".$row['nome_da_coluna']."</p>";
}
```